# RXSwift, Reentrancy anomaly was detected

Tags: swift, xcode, system.reactive, rx-swift

I'm beginner in RXSwift, and i have problem with my code

I have code:

```
let dartScore = PublishSubject<Int>()
            dartScore.asObservable()
                .scan(501) { intermediate, newValue in
                    let result = intermediate - newValue
                    return result >= 0 ? result : intermediate
                }
                .do(onNext: {
                    if $0 == 0 {
                        dartScore.onCompleted()
                    }
                })
                .subscribe({
                    print($0.isStopEvent ? $0 : $0.element!)
                })
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

            dartScore.onNext(13)
            dartScore.onNext(50)
            dartScore.onNext(60)
            dartScore.onNext(378)
```

And i get error:

> ⚠️ Reentrancy anomaly was detected. ⚠️
>
> Debugging: To debug this issue you can set a breakpoint in /****RxSwift/RxSwift/Rx.swift:97 and observe the call stack.
>
> Problem: This behavior is breaking the observable sequence grammar. `next (error | completed)?`
>       This behavior breaks the grammar because there is overlapping between sequence events.
>       Observable sequence is trying to send an event before sending of previous event has finished.

why i can't do ".onCompleted()" inside .do(onNext), and what should i do to avoid the warning?

I'm using XCode 9.0, swift 4, RXSwift 4.0.0

Thank you

Best Regards

Comment: I'm a Rx.NET guy, but I assume RxSwift behaves the same way - so don't do `.onCompleted()` inside the `do`. You probably want to use `takeWhile`.

Comment: Thank you for suggest, @Enigmtivity,
Regards

Comment: I got this issue because of completely unrelated code. If you just follow the instruction and set breakpoint and observe the stack, you can trace the issue. For me, I was observing a text field and calculating and setting other values. So the code to calculate other values was calling `view.endEditing(true)` and because of that it was going into a loop of edit and end edit..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do the `.onCompleted()` inside the `.onNext()` because you would have the observable eating its own tail in that case. This causes a memory cycle as well.

As @Enigmativity suggested in the comments, you should use `takeWhile()` to handle this situation:

```
dartScore.asObservable()
    .scan(501) { intermediate, newValue in
        let result = intermediate - newValue
        return result >= 0 ? result : intermediate
    }
    .takeWhile { $0 != 0 }
    .subscribe({
        print($0.isStopEvent ? $0 : $0.element!)
    })
```

The above produces a new observable that completes when the value is 0.

Comment: Oh, Okay, Understood, thank you for the answer :)
Regards

Comment: I have two consececutive lines like this: `observer.onNext("Hello world")
;observer.onCompleted()`
Is that wrong?

Comment: @Honey No, that's fine (assuming you didn't put those two lines inside a closure tied to `observer`.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly connected to the OP's problem, but I came here when searching for `Reentrancy anomaly was detected`, and for me the reason was simply that I removed an `addSubview(viewInQuestion)` line in the code for an NSView on MacOs, while still using the `viewInQuestion` in the constraints setup ... adding the `viewInQuestion` as a subview solved the issue.